# Prometheus arithmetic operators: default values for missing matches?

Tags: prometheus

I want to do a query like: `success_count/(success_count + failure_count)` but label combinations that are missing in `failure_count` won't show up in the result.

E.g.: Let's say I have:

```
success_count{name="a"} = 8
failure_count{name="a"} = 2
success_count{name="b"} = 10
```

I would like the query result to be:

```
{name="a"} = 0.8
{name="b"} = 1.0
```

But it actually is:

```
{name="a"} = 0.8
```

Is there a way to chose a default value of 0 for `failure_count` whenever it's missing? Or some other way to preserve all label combinations from the left-hand side?